# Adding custom styles for select box

Tags: html, css, select

I need to add some custom styles to HTML select box completely changing its default style. 
This is how my select box should be after adding custom styles.

[image]

[image]

I could have to get these styles to certain level. But still not 100%.

This is my HTML and CSS.

```
<span class="custom-dropdown large">
    <select class="select select_large">
        <option>Select an Option</option>
        <option>Option One</option>
        <option>Option Two</option>
        <option>Option Three</option>
        <option>Option Four</option>
        <option>Option Five</option>
    </select>
</span>

    .large {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .select{
        font-size: inherit; 
        padding: 10px; 
        margin: 0; 
    }

    .select_large {
        background-color: #001848;
        color: #fff;   

    }       

    .select_large option{
        background-color: #dadada;
        color: #000;    
        border: none;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }       

    .select_large option::hover {
        background-color: #20b390;
    }

    @supports (pointer-events: none) and
              ((-webkit-appearance: none) or
              (-moz-appearance: none) or
              (appearance: none)) {

        .custom-dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .select {
            padding-right: 40px;                
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;    
        }       

        .custom-dropdown::before,
        .custom-dropdown::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .custom-dropdown::after { /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
            content: "\25BC";
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 15px;
            right: 10px;
            top: 50%; 
            margin-top: -5px;
        }


        .custom-dropdown::before { /*  Custom dropdown arrow cover */
            width: 40px;
            right: 0; 
            top: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        }

        .large::before {
            background-color: #001848;
            //background-color: #dadada;
        }

        .large::after {
            color: #dadada;
            //color: #434343;
        }

        @-moz-document url-prefix() {
            .select                     { padding-right: .9em }
            .large .select      { padding-right: 40px }
            .small .select  { padding-right: .5em }
        }
    }
```

This is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wg0fmud1/)

Hope somebody will help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: I have looked into this (I needed a similar solution for my own website), and, sadly, there really isn't a way to style the hovered or selected options using the native select.

Comment: @Blubberguy22, Can we have any alternative solution with pure CSS to reach for this style?

Comment: Partially, you can style most of the select (with limitations of course, i.e. pictures don't work very well), with the exception of the selected and hovered options (because these are styled by the OS).

Comment: Check my fiddle.. I have reached to some level. But hover is the main problem

Comment: I know, you can't style a select's hover.

Comment: Check this -http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index.html

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. but there is not using `select` element

Comment: Yes, the only way to work around this is by using something other than a basic select element.

Answer (score 0):

Selects are really annoying to style. This is because they depend on the browser and operating system and therefore parts of them are not style-able. For example, you can change the background color of the options, but if an option is selected, the styling gets messed up (you can't change the color of the selected option).

Try looking into some jQuery plugins like `ms-Dropdown`: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Not an answer to his problem.

Comment: I know, but it really can't be done well with native selects.

Comment: Not an answer, but as a senior front end dev, really good advice :P

Comment: Don't make a fake SELECT box, complete waste of time imo. Just style the select box when you are not interacting with it like how you have. Looks great!

Comment: Some plugins are helpful for doing this; edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet is to find a js plugin that will render a dynamic  with custom styling while maintaining the functionality of your .

The problem with customizing  with custom CSS is that its usually the OS who styles them and its looks change from OS to OS considerably, making it nearly impossible to style in an uniform matter with pure CSS.

simply do a search for 'jquery selectbox' or 'jquery custom select'

Comment: I am looking for solution with pure CSS

Comment: Yes we are aware, but it is practically impossible to style select boxes on an uniform way with pure CSS.